# When is the crossed sword and baton alone? When does it appear with the crown?

Tags: canada

Brigadier-General Steven Moritsugu [wears merely the crossed sword and baton on his shoulder](http://nikkeivoice.ca/steven-moritsugu-promoted-to-rank-of-brigadier-general/)

[image]

[but here, his crossed sword and baton is sandwiched between the crown and maple leaf](http://nikkeivoice.ca/brig-gen-moritsugu-appointed-officer-of-the-order-of-military-merit/).

[image]

[Brigadier-General Rob Roy Mackenzie wears merely the crossed sword and baton](https://www.seaforthhighlanders.ca/seaforthnews/brigadier-general-rob-roy-mackenzie-a-seasoned-officer-leads-the-army-reserve-into-the-future)

[image]

[but here, his crossed sword and baton is sandwiched between the crown and maple leaf](https://globalnews.ca/news/1083957/vancouver-soldier-recognized-for-bravery-following-ambush-in-afghanistan/).

[image]

Comment: im not entirely familiar with canada's uniforms but i think the uniforms with medals are the #1 ceremonial kit (worn for ceremonies and state events) and the other is the #3 formal service dress kit.

Comment: This is not a history question... Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @BrianZ **how isn't this "a history question"?**

Comment: @user35395 It's about the present, not the past.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for new users is that if none of the verbs in your question are past tense, its probably off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[per Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Armed_Forces_ranks_and_insignia), it seems to have been an overall insignia change and not a context-specific one - it just didn't last very long.

> On 8 July 2013, Minister of National Defence Peter MacKay announced the intention to reintroduce a more traditional style Canadian Army officers' rank insignia. ... The new insignia for officers, instead of using the current British rank insignia for brigadier (used in the Canadian Army until 1968), had the pre-1920 brigadier-general insignia (crossed sabre and baton) instead.
>
> On 2 April 2016, the Commander of the Canadian Army announced that general officers would revert to the unification-era rank insignia worn between 1968 and 2013. This rank insignia is based on the shoulder board rank insignia of Royal Canadian Navy flag officers. The rank insignia of general officers now consists of a crown, crossed sabre and baton, and a series of maple leaves on shoulder straps.

The "traditional style" 2013-16 is sabre-batons only, the pre-2013 and post-2016 ones have crowns. It's a little unclear when those changes actually happened rather than "were announced that..." but I suspect it will align well with the dates of the photos.

The dates of the photos seem to fit with this - a little wiggle room around the exact dates of when those changes came into force rather than when they were announced, and it seems to explain the insignia used.